# Can "event Action<>" be invoked with 3 type arguments using fakeiteasy in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fakeiteasy

I have looked quite a lot on the internet but somehow I am not grasping the concept to solve my problem. It should not be that complicated.

I have a SUT (System Under Test), which has an event action like:

```
    event Action<ISomeInterface, bool, string> DownloadFinished;
```

Now i want to raise this event using the fake object (using fakeiteasy), like:

```
fakeObject.DownloadFinished  = Raise.With<ISomeInterface, bool, string>();
```

but the above line shows error as it says "Raise cannot take 3 arguments". Could someone recommend how to solve this issue.

Comment: According to my reading of [the docs](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/raising-events/), if you're using a non-`EventHandler` event, you need to use `Raise.FreeForm.With`. I haven't tried this.

Comment: It works, you could make it like an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my reading of [the docs](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/raising-events/), if you're using a non-`EventHandler` event, you need to use `Raise.FreeForm.With`:

```
fakeObject.DownloadFinished += Raise.FreeForm.With(implementerOfSomeInterface, false, string.Empty);
```

or similar